# How to track the current values of slider elements in the below code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the HTML code,

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 400px; margin: 100px auto; padding: 40px;">


<div id="double_number_range" style="margin-top: 50px;"></div>
```

External Links: (Added into my project structure), The range slider functionality is defined here.

```
range_picker.min.js and range_picker.min.css
```

Script code:

```
$("#double_number_range").rangepicker({
            type: "double",
            startValue: 0, 
            endValue: 100,      
        translateSelectLabel: function(currentPosition, totalPosition) 
        {
                return parseInt(100 * (currentPosition / totalPosition));
        }

});
```

Output:
[image: Range Slider]
How can I submit the startValue and endValue to a form, after the slider values are changed?
* I have tried console.log(startValue) and copying it into local variable inside the script method.
After every change on the slider, the values are passed into some methods defined in the range_picker.min.js.

Comment: What library are you using for your range picker? Is there an API available for it?

Comment: `How can I submit the startValue and endValue to a form` do you really mean how can you submit the values the user has set?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you are using [this](https://github.com/zhangtasdq/range-picker) library.

There's a `getSelectValue` function that returns an object such as
 `{start: 0, startLabel: "0", end: 378, endLabel: "100", totalWidth: 378}`

You can just call `getSelectValue` whenever you need the values and use the `startLabel` and `endLabel`.  You can set the values of two hidden inputs in your form or if you're using ajax to submit the form, use the values directly.

```js
;(function() {
    "use strict";

   var rangepicker= $("#double_number_range").rangepicker({
        type: "double",
        startValue: 0,
        endValue: 100,
        translateSelectLabel: function(currentPosition, totalPosition) {
            return parseInt(100 * (currentPosition / totalPosition));
        }
    });

  $("#btn").on("click", function(){
      var start = rangepicker.getSelectValue().startLabel;
      var end = rangepicker.getSelectValue().endLabel;
      
      $("#startVal").text(start);
      $("#endVal").text(end);
      $("#startInput").val(start);
      $("#endInput").val(end);
    });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/zhangtasdq/range-picker/master/dist/css/range-picker.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/zhangtasdq/range-picker/master/dist/js/range_picker.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Get Values</button><br/>
Start:<span id="startVal"></span><br/>
End:<span id="endVal"></span><br/>
<input type="text" id="startInput" placeholder="Start Value"/>
<input type="text" id="endInput" placeholder="End Value" />
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 400px; padding: 40px;">
    <div id="double_number_range" style="margin-top: 50px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to populate the changed values, automatically to the text fields provided? There by eliminating the need to click the "GET VALUES" Button.? @lamelemon